# display only specific rows in a column with a group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm somewhat new to Oracle SQL and can't figure this out.  I want to display the rows with the high value in the third column.  Here is my table i'm working with:

```
theyear custseg     sales    
2010    Corporate   573637.62
2010    Home Office 515314.98
2010    Small Biz   390361.94
2010    Consumer    383825.67
2011    Corporate   731208
2011    Home Office 521274.34
2011    Consumer    390967.03
2011    Small Biz   273264.81
2012    Corporate   823861.38
2012    Consumer    480082.9
2012    Home Office 478106.93
```

I want the highest value grouped by year.  If I do a group by with just the year I get the answer somewhat, but I can't include/display customer segment (ugh). It just displays the year and the max sales.   When I include the customer segment it gives me that table, which displays all the sales - not what i'm looking for.    I simply want the rows that contain the MAX sales given the year (theyear) AND the customer segment (custseg).  For what it's worth here is the code I used to create the above:

```
select theyear, custseg, max(totalsales) sales from (
select custseg, extract(year from ordshipdate) theyear, sum(ordsales) TotalSales from customers, orderdet
where customers.custid = orderdet.custid
group by custseg, extract(year from ordshipdate)
order by sum(ordsales) desc)
group by theyear, custseg
order by theyear, max(totalsales) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all fields are in the customer table as described in the question, the following query would do what you want:

```
select c.theyear, c.custseg, c.sales
from 
customer c inner join
(
  select theyear, max(sales) as max_sales_in_year
  from customer
  group by theyear
) maxvalues
on (
     c.year = maxvalues.theyear and
     c.sales = maxvalues.max_sales_in_year
   );
```

Swap the inner join with a **right outer join** if you do not plan to settle ties arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT theyear, custseg, totalsales FROM
(
 select theyear, custseg, totalsales, 
 ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY theyear ORDER BY totalsales DESC) rn 
 from 
 (
  select custseg, extract(year from ordshipdate) theyear, sum(ordsales) TotalSales 
  from  customers, orderdet
  where customers.custid = orderdet.custid
  group by custseg, extract(year from ordshipdate)
 ) a
) b
WHERE rn = 1;
```

BTW, the query above will look more readable when using CTE:

```
WITH a AS(
select custseg, extract(year from ordshipdate) theyear, sum(ordsales) TotalSales 
from  customers, orderdet
where customers.custid = orderdet.custid
group by custseg, extract(year from ordshipdate)),
b AS (
select theyear, custseg, totalsales, 
ROW_NUMBER OVER(PARTITION BY theyear ORDER BY totalsales DESC) rn 
FROM a)
SELECT theyear, custseg, totalsales
FROM b;
```